# Daily money system for discord server not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, discord.net

I am trying to implement a daily payment system (fake server currency) using a Discord Bot and the discord.Net api wrapper. My code does appear to correctly update that balance and recognize date changes, but it does not seem to remember who has collected their daily payment. Please help. Thanks.

```
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AmberScript3.Modules
{
    public class DailyMoney : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        List<string> users = new List<string>();
        string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

        [Command("money daily")]
        public async Task DailyCash()
        {
            string author = Context.Message.Author.Username;
            if(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") != currentDate)
            {
                users.Clear();
            }
            if(users.Contains(author))
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You have already reclaimed your daily payment!");
            }
            else
            {
                users.Add(author);
                Random r = new Random();
                int seed = r.Next(1000);
                double val = Math.Round(r.NextDouble() * seed, 2);
                Money.AddBalance(Context.Message.Author.Username, val);
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Added ${val} to {author}'s account as a daily payment.");
            }
            currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: You'll likely need to persist the users somewhere (file, database, etc).  Every time this class is instantiated the `users` list is reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DailyMoney class is abstract, and so every instantiated version of it will have different values. I would store things you want to keep between instantiations in text files locally, and then grab them in the code on creation. If you really wanted, you could keep all these values in a separate class, and use Newtonsoft.Json's `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to store it. There is lots of documentation for that stuff online. Although, just for one List of Strings, just store it in a text file.